# PHP/PDO Select queries

Tags: php, pdo

I am using the following queries to select rows from a mysql database using PDO.

I am using this code to select multiple rows:

```
<?php
        $contact = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from contacts WHERE company_sequence = :company_sequence AND contactstatus = :contactstatus ");
        $contact->execute(array(':contactstatus' => '', ':company_sequence' => $ticket["company"]));
        ?>
        <select name="contactsequence" id="contactsequence">
        <?php foreach($contact as $contacts) {
            echo '<option value="'.$contacts["sequence"].'" ';
            if($ticket["contact"] == $contacts["sequence"]) {
                echo 'selected="selected"';
            }
            echo '>'.$contacts['forename'].' '.$contacts["surname"].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
```

And this for selecting a single row:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("select * from tickets where ticketnumber = :seq ");
$stmt->execute(array(':seq' => $_GET["seq"]));
$ticket = $stmt->fetch();
```

Is the the correct way to run PDO select queries? (Preventing sql injection etc) I have been looking online but I just wanted to double check

Comment: Other things aside, you are close, but on the first set you are attempting to loop on the STMT statement. Might need to change that foreach to atleast be foreach ($contact->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $contacts) { /// }. Is this question related to an error? Is it not working?

Comment: Could I do $contact->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) then leave my loop as foreach($contact as $contacts) { ... }

Comment: I am very new to PDO so you may have to be patient. I started learning it 2/3 days ago lol :)

Comment: No, the function of ::fetchAll() is to return a set of results. Make it $results = $contact->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); foreach ($results as $contact) { /// }

Comment: The documentation online has ample examples to bring you up to speed. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Ok I will give that a go. Can u put that as an answer please

Answer (score 1):

Charlie,

You can convert to this bit of code for a couple reasons. A: Readable. B: Error Checking

Your foreach(...) will throw an error if you pass it an empty result set. `foreach` trusts that you are feeding it a legitimate array.

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM `contacts`
WHERE `company_sequence` = :companySequence AND
`contactstatus` = :contactStatus";

$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':contactStatus' => '', 
    ':companySequence' => $ticket["company"])
);

$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$records) {
    // NO RECORDS FOUND
    die('No records found.');
}

foreach ($records as $contact) {
    // Do what you want with each result
}
```

This is a little cleaner way to do things and provides some very minimal error / no result found checking.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it, is right  although I prefer to separate my database stuff from the html output stuff.

You do not have to fetch all rows in a big result set and you can loop directly over the `$contact` object because the [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object implements [`Traversable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), making it suitable to loop over with a `foreach` loop.

One thing I would recommend though, is to add error handling. Using exceptions, you can put your database calls in a `try` - `catch` block, making it easy to detect and take action when things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Jeroen! I don't know how many times I've looked at the PDOStatement docs and never picked up on the Traversible. That's handy.